# hp x360 battery dies at 60% and is unable to calibrate properly

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, hp-pavilion, hp

i replaced my laptop battery a few months ago (near the end of 2022) due to having a faulty battery (it would only work when plugged in). since getting this (non-hp) battery, it wouldn’t calibrate and i thought nothing of it as it charged from 0-100 completely fine.
since then, it’s been shutting off way too quickly (first at 15, then 20, then 40, now 60) and isn’t able to drain to 0% so i could retry calibration. is there a way to fix this *without* getting a new battery?? i’m quite adamant on keeping the battery as it’s still well functioning for that remaining 40% i can use along with the fact i cannot afford to buy a 3rd battery…it also shuts off without warning and using the “long press the power button for 15/30/60 seconds” method isn’t working at all, even when removing the ac adapter and battery, and vice versa.

Comment: *"it wouldn’t calibrate"* - that's your problem right there. If you can't calibrate it, the computer doesn't know when it's full or flat. It's guesswork anyway, but if it hasn't had a chance to reset calibration, it doesn't have a clue what's going on.

Comment: i know that’s my problem but how exactly do i fix it?

Comment: Tell us what you tried to get it to calibrate & any error message you saw. All the rest of this is pretty much irrelevant background.

Comment: i’ve received no error messages beside “battery calibration needed (20)” from the hp pc diagnostics uefi *after* doing calibration twice. i’ve also taken out the battery, held the power button for 60 seconds (without the ac adapter) and put it back in to drain the battery. i’ve also done it *with* the adapter but to no avail. i’ve also attempted it with the battery and ac adapter in, along with calibration using the hp pc diagnostics uefi as said before.

Comment: Standard method to calibrate a new battery [may change between manufacturers]. Charge without powering on for 24h. Run without allowing sleep until it shuts down. Charge again to 100%. Done.

Comment: thanks for the help, i’ll see if it works and update!

Comment: Ahhh… when flat, wait 5 hrs before 2nd charge.

Answer (score -1):

If your laptop shuts down without warning and pressing the power button for a longer time fails, remove only the battery, keep the mains line connected and try to restart then. Once the operating system is up and running you can try connecting your battery and see if it starts being charged.

The recipe worked on my Thinkpad laptop.

As for your battery you probably have one or more defective or wore down cells. Replacing them has become difficult as laptop manufacturers use tamper-resistent charging ICs to prevent this repair case for some good liability reasons.

If you don't know somebody who can repair your rechargeable battery for free you have to bite the bullet and buy a new one.

Upon purchase test the new battery with some deep cycles and monitor the battery parameters as to get a rough idea if the capacity degrades too fast so that you can claim a replacement during the guarantee period.

Comment: i’ve done this step-by-step, it seems to only be charging from the fact it was at 90% before removal (i was using it prior), does this make a difference? either way, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "i’ve done this step-by-step". And when your battery is at 90% there is no need to remove it.